# CMDeviceMotion returns 0 values for magnetic field

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad, magnetometer

I am developing iOS app with compass functionality. I have tried to use `CMMagnetometerData` updates which give uncalibrated, but normal results.

After that I tried to get `CMDeviceMotion` updates which turned out to give always zero magnetic field with `CMMagneticFieldCalibrationAccuracyUncalibrated` accuracy. The only device I have is an iPad, so can't test on others.

May be field is zero because sensor is not calibrated, but I could not find any way to perform calibration.

How to fix that?

**UPDATE:**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556859/coremotion-magneticfield-is-always-0) is suggested to use `startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:toQueue:withHandler:`, however it didn't work for me.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28367541/1555653) is suggested to set `showsDeviceMovementDisplay` to `true`. However it didn't work either, calibration windows is just not popping up.

Finally, **SOLVED**. According to my observations:

1) Use `startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:toQueue:withHandler:` with `referenceFrame` NOT equal to `allZeros` or `XArbitraryZVertical`.

2) Set `showsDeviceMovementDisplay` to `true`.

After few zero-value updates with accuracy `CMMagneticFieldCalibrationAccuracyUncalibrated` it will normalise.

**CODE:**

```
...
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.05
motionManager.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true 
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame(CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.XArbitraryCorrectedZVertical, toQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler:handleUpdate)
...
private func handleUpdate(data: CMDeviceMotion!, error: NSError!) {
    if data != nil {
        let field = data.magneticField.field
        println("\(field.x), \(field.y), \(field.z)")
    }
}
```

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally, according to my own observations:

1) Use `startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:toQueue:withHandler:`with `referenceFrame` NOT equal to `allZeros` or `XArbitraryZVertical`.

2) Set `showsDeviceMovementDisplay` to `true`.

After few zero-value updates with accuracy `CMMagneticFieldCalibrationAccuracyUncalibrated` it will normalise.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. Really helped me in my situation!

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this solution to fit Swift 5.6.1.

The following code also shows how to read other motion data altogether.

`data!.magneticField.accuracy.rawValue` will return something else rather than -1.

**CODE:**

```
// MARK: gyroscope acceleration magnitude orientation gravity all-at-once
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01
// for calibrated magnetic field
motionManager.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical, to: OperationQueue.main) { (data, error) in
    // handle device motion updates
    if isPlaying {
        if timeT.isEmpty {
            startTime = data!.timestamp
        }
        timeT.append(data!.timestamp - startTime)
        // get gyroscope sensor data
        gyroX.append(data!.rotationRate.x)
        gyroY.append(data!.rotationRate.y)
        gyroZ.append(data!.rotationRate.z)
        // get accelerometer sensor data
        accX.append(data!.userAcceleration.x)
        accY.append(data!.userAcceleration.y)
        accZ.append(data!.userAcceleration.z)
        // get magnetometer sensor data
        // data!.magneticField.accuracy
        magX.append(data!.magneticField.field.x)
        magY.append(data!.magneticField.field.y)
        magZ.append(data!.magneticField.field.z)
        // get attitude orientation
        oriPitch.append(data!.attitude.pitch)
        oriYaw.append(data!.attitude.yaw)
        oriRoll.append(data!.attitude.roll)
        // get gravity vector
        // motion.gravity.x
        // motion.gravity.y
        // motion.gravity.z
        
        // debug
        print(data!.timestamp - startTime)
        print(data!.rotationRate)
        print(data!.userAcceleration)
        print(data!.magneticField.accuracy.rawValue)
        print(data!.magneticField.field)
        print(data!.attitude)
    }
}
```

Comment: using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical helped me, thanks!