# iOS magnetometer vector has unexpected values

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, core-motion

When obtaining the magnetic north vector from the magnetometer on iOS there are three ways I know of to do it. Only the first method appears to give reasonable results. The phone is flat on it's back and it's long axis is pointing `97° E` according to the Compass app.

1. `CLLocationManager` delegate overload `didUpdateHeading`. This gives `CLHeading` with `(x,y,z)` vector of `(-18.4, -15.3 -44.9)` along with other helpful items such as magnetic/true heading, accuracy, timestamp.

This seems reasonable!

2. `CMMotionManager` `startMagnetometerUpdates`. This gives `CMMagneticField` with `(x,y,z)` vector of `(36.5, -10.1, -375)`. To be clear, the Z-axis value is negative three hundred and seventy five microteslas. This does not seem reasonable. If I rotate the phone the `z` value fluctuates, but not below `-283` and that's when the phone is inverted from where it provided the result above.

Is this the internal magnetic field that has not yet been filtered out?

3. `CMMotionManager` `startDeviceMotionUpdates`. This gives `CMCalibratedMagneticField` with property `field` with `(x,y,z)` vector of `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. This seems to be returning no meaningful data, although the events are firing rapidly and consistently.

Why isn't this returning any values?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be right about `CMMagneticField` the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmagnetometerdata/1616084-magneticfield) specify that it includes "bias introduced from the device itself and its surroundings."

As far as I can tell, when `CMMotionManager` returns a vector of `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` that means it is not [properly calibrated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmagneticfieldcalibrationaccuracy/uncalibrated). You can check the accuracy value to make sure of this. A useful guide to calibrating your device can be found in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840844/cmdevicemotion-returns-0-values-for-magnetic-field).

Note: the magnetic field returned by the `CMMotionManager` is not the same `CMMagneticField` returned by the magnetometer and therefore does not include the bias from the device. See the `var magneticField: CMCalibratedMagneticField` field [within the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmdevicemotion/1616140-magneticfield).

Comment: Thank you! A question: how can `CLLocationManager` `didUpdateHeading` provide good, clean, accurate results if `CMMotionManager` `startDeviceMotionUpdates` is showing as not calibrated? I would expect them to share the same calibration. Do they have separate calibration profiles?